# Jquery mobile open individual feed items on separate page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have this code which is supposed to be an RSS reader using JQuery, HTML5 and CSS.

The challenge is that, I'm trying to open each individual feed item on a separate page after clicking on the title.

I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here's my code:

```
function getRSSFeed(feed) {

     var qryRSS = 'select * from rss where url=' + '"' + feed + '"';

     $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql", {

         q: qryRSS,
         format: "json"
     },

     function (data) {

         for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)

         {
             var con = data.query.results.item[i].link;
             $('#body-content').append(' <a href ="#page2"><div id="rss-bdy">' + data.query.results.item[i].encoded + '</a></div>');
             $('#body-content').append('<hr>')
             $('#body-content').append('<a href ="#page2"><div id="rss-ttle"><h4>' + data.query.results.item[i].title + '</h4></a></div>');
             $('#body-content').append('<p id="rss-dte">' + data.query.results.item[i].pubDate + '</p><br>');
             $('#body-content2').append('<div id="full-article">' + con + '</div>');

         }


         $(function () {
             $("#rssDivBody").rssDivBody();
         });
     });
 };


 getRSSFeed('meps4wildlife.eu/feed');
```

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/smjs6m87/ ?

Comment: This worked for me! Apparently I was missing a few important declarations and an extra function You're a genius man!